# Angular scope, controller nesting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a loading screen to show when I'm storing data to the server, but it doesn't update until I finish my `$http` request. Can somebody explain why?

Controllers:

```
app.controller('controller1',controller1); 
controller1.$inject=['$scope', '$http', 'myService', 'basketService']; 
function controller1($scope, $http, myService, basketService) {
    //code    
};

app.controller('controller2',controller2); 
controller2.$inject=['$scope', '$http', 'myService', 'basketService']; 
function controller2($scope, $http, myService, basketService) {
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
        $scope.iWantToUpdateThis = true;
    };    
};
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="controller1">
    <div ng-cloak ng-show="iWantToUpdateThis">
    </div>
    //code
    <button ng-controller="controller2" ng-click="doSomething()">
        clickMe
    </button>
<body>
```

I've tried using `$scope.$apply()`, but it says that a digest loop is already on execution.

Comment: $scope.$apply() not scope.apply()

Comment: try using $timeout(function(){$scope.iWantToUpdateThis = true});

Comment: Have you thought about using $rootScope to store the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.iWantToUpdateThis = true;` is in 'controller1' while you update its value in 'controller2'

You've go to change the function in controller2 to:

`$scope.$parent.iWantToUpdateThis = true;`

Here I've made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yKcNTNVNRaZqk1AgZMu5?p=preview) for you.